# How to include OrderBy in Linq Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, radcombobox

I want to apply OrderBy Ascending on SelectionName ,there by sorting the items in radcombobox

```
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items.Select(x => new RadComboBoxItem(x.SelectionName, x.SelectionValue)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Just add `OrderBy` before `ToArray()`: `.OrderBy(x => x.selectionName)` in your case

Comment: Thanks it is working can you me how to include more than one parameter in OrderBy clause i.e i want to OrderBy(SelectionName,SortOrder) in Query

Comment: Please see my answer for multiple sorting columns.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items
  .OrderBy(x => x.SelectionName)
  .Select(x => new RadComboBoxItem(x.SelectionName, x.SelectionValue))
  .ToArray());
```

As you commented you wish to sort by additional values you can use `.ThenBy(x => x.Value)`.

In your case;

```cs
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items
  .OrderBy(x => x.SelectionName)
  .ThenBy(x => x.SortOrder)
  .Select(x => new RadComboBoxItem(x.SelectionName, x.SelectionValue))
  .ToArray());
```

Comment: This doesn't work. RadComboBoxItem doesn't have a `SelectionName` property. Either use its `Text` property or sort the source collection instead of the resulting RadComboBoxItems

Comment: Fixed by ordering before creating the RadComboBoxItems.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the items before adding them to the combo box:

```
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items
    .OrderBy(x=>x.SelectionName)
    .Select(x=>new RadComboBoxItem(x.SelectionName,x.SelectionValue)
    .ToArray());
```

You probalby don't need to call `ToArray()` because `AddRange` may work with IEnumerable. I haven't checked *all* RadComboBox classes, but at least the [AJAX version](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/m_telerik_web_ui_radcomboboxitemcollection_addrange.html) works with an IEnumerable.

A better option would be to use the binding support in you platform (ASP.NET, WPF, Windows Forms ?) to bind your combo to an ordered enumerable of items, instead of constructing raw combobox items.

**UPDATE**

To order by more than one field, use an anonymous type with the desired fields, eg:

```
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items
    .OrderBy(x=>new {x.SortOrder,x.SelectionName})
    ...
```

`OrderBy`'s argument is a lambda *function* that creates the order key.

When you specify `x=>x.SelectionName` you are specifying a function that receives an item `x` and returns the contents of the `SelectionName` property as the key.

When you type `x=>new {x.SortOrder,x.SelectionName}`, you specify a function that returns an anonymous type with field filled from the `SortOrder` and `SelectionName` parameters.

It's clearer to use LINQ syntax instead of the LINQ methods in this case. The same code can be written as:

```
var orderedItems=from item in items
                 orderby item.SortOrder,item.SelectionName
                 select new RadComboBoxItem(item.SelectionName,item.SelectionValue);
dropDown.Items.AddRange(orderedItems);
```

Comment: Thank You it is working,can you tell me how to include more than one Parameter in OrderBy i.e OrderBy(SortOrder,SelectionName)

Comment: Return the fields as an anonymous type, eg `OrderBy(x=>new {x.SortOrder, x.SelectionName})`

Answer (score 0):

this will help:

```
dropDown.Items.AddRange(items
  .Select(x => new RadComboBoxItem(x.SelectionName, x.SelectionValue))
  .OrderBy(x => x.SelectionName)
  .ToArray());
```

Comment: This doesn't work. RadComboBoxItem doesn't have a `SelectionName` property. Either use its `Text` property or sort the source collection instead of the resulting RadComboBoxItems